# Understanding Facebook SDK app requests vs app invitations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-invite

I registered a Facebook app that is basically the website, it doesn't run at Facebook like those browser games.

I want the site users that register with Facebook to be able to invite their friends, I did this by using "requests", it opens a Facebook hosted URL where I select the friends to invite, looks like this:

[image]

But these requests only show on receiver's end if he/she goes [here](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests) , I don't even where to click to reach that page, and from other users I receive invitations to apps that they show in top right corner under the globe icon, **how do I do that** ? Or is that limited to "canvas" applications that run directly on Facebook ? 
Are there different ways to invite people to an app ?

**I want the receiver to see it like this:**

[image]

**Not like this:**

[image]

Comment: First of all, there is no difference between requests and invites – both are technically the same, only a request send to a user who is not using the app yet is _called_ an “invite”. And requests are only available for canvas apps, not for external websites.

Comment: I don't understand, my app is a website, not a canvas app, and I sent requests as I mentioned in the post. Receiver was already an app user. I tried removing app from receiver's end and the request was no longer shown at all.

Comment: What part of _“requests are only available for canvas apps, not for external websites”_ don’t you understand?

Comment: The part where my app is an external website and not a canvas app, and where I *did* sent requests/invites (the screens above), that confuses the hell out of me.

Answer (score 1):

As @CBroe has already stated, Invites / Requests are limited to Canvas Apps (Apps that work within Facebook) or Mobile Apps. The app category also has to be configured to be a game (another category won't work).

The facebook documentation says:
`Requests are currently only available for games on Canvas, iOS or Android.`

In order for the Request to work, you need to configure the Canvas Page URL:
`When a user accepts a request, either through the notification jewel, the beeper popup, or App Center they will be sent to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the request.`

Read up on the [Request documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests).

Comment: I see what the documentation says but what I tested shows otherwise. I sent the invite/requests from my site, when receiver accepts it, he is sent to my site and the request ID is mentioned in the URL variables.

Comment: In order to get the Request notification like you've requested, the app needs to be configured as a Game.